# Multiple different Bluescreen every other day (driver and hardware errors)

Tags: windows-10, hardware-failure, nvidia-graphics-card, bluescreenview

The computer that I recently bought keeps getting a blue screen every other day. I installed the MSI-Afterburn software and uploaded last blue screen log . image and link of hml is attached.

Can any anyone help me find out which part is the problem?

System configuration:

- **VGA**: Gigabyte 3050 8GB
- **RAM**: 2 x 8GB 2666 Gloway
- **CPU**: 10400f

MSI log file [can be found here](https://www.mediafire.com/file/ucsrf20y2gt3xcf/HardwareMonitoring.zip/file).

last bluescreen dumb: https://www.mediafire.com/file/cjn43a0oqwb9mm4/122922-8046-01.dmp/file

BlueScreen1

> [image: BlueScreen1]

BlueScreen2

> [image: BlueScreen2]

BlueScreen3

> [image: BlueScreen3]

Comment: different bluescreens are an indication of a bad memory stick, test your memory.

Comment: memory stick was broken and warranty change it once. could you see msi log to find out real problem

Comment: Are you able to edit your question with the relevant lines of the log (driver and hardware errors).  Better attach the Mini dmp file to your question. All of this for all of us to see.  Get the PC Manufacturer's Hardware Diagnostic App and run that. What results?

Comment: bluescreens make no mini dmp log. it sticks on 0%.

Comment: Run Hardware Diagnostics to help pinpoint the error

Comment: “The computer that I recently bought keeps getting a blue screen every other day.” You should return the whole PC as defective for a full refund and take your money elsewhere. Simple as that.

Comment: If hardware, I agree with @Giacomo1968.  The point of running hardware tests is that, if hardware is fine, it may be you need to back up and reinstall Windows.

Comment: The log file was submitted as a .zip and as a result I am uncomfortable downloading a compressed file. What should should be done is the relevant information should be provided in the question body as formatted text.

Comment: That is why I asked the OP to edit the question to include relevant sections of the log. I, too, do not wish to download the zip file

Comment: In many regions, buyers are protected when merchandise is faulty. In the USA, it is called a "lemon law" (i.e., the fruit smells good but when you bite into it you find it too sour). You're already on record as finding issues -- return it for a full repair or replacement, if possible.

Comment: I upload last dumb file:https://www.mediafire.com/file/cjn43a0oqwb9mm4/122922-8046-01.dmp/file